# How to use multiple inheritance for implementing different comparison logic?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to use interface IComparable (not in this mockup code) and its 2 implementations to work on same object.
I must use operators to do so.
I would like to do it without resolving like here c.right::operator--().

Here I have interfaces Common and Uni both inherited by Inter. Then I have right and left that blend into custom class implementing both Common and 2 versions of Uni interfaces.
2 different versions meaning one that uses operator to call f() and the other to call g().

```
#include<iostream>

class Common {
   public:
       Common() { std::cout << "common\n"; }
};

class Uni {
public:
   Uni() { std::cout << "uni\n"; }
   virtual void operator--() = 0;
};

class Inter : virtual public Common, public Uni {
public:
    Inter() { std::cout << "inter\n"; }
};

class left : public Inter {
public:
    left() { std::cout << "left\n"; }
    void operator--() override { f(); }
    virtual void f() = 0;
};


class right : public Inter {
public:
   right() { std::cout << "right\n"; }
   void operator--() override { g(); }
   virtual void g() = 0;
};

class custom : public right, public left {
public:
   custom() { std::cout << "custom\n"; }
   void f() override { std::cout << "lol\n"; }
   void g() override { std::cout << "gfunc\n"; }
};

class custom2 : public right, public left {
public:
   custom2() { std::cout << "custom2\n"; }
   void f() override { std::cout << "lol2\n"; }
   void g() override { std::cout << "gfunc2\n"; }
};

 int main()  
 {
    custom c;
    custom2 c2;

    c.left::operator--();
    c.right::operator--();  
    c2.right::operator--();
  }
```

Comment: If you want `custom::operator--` to always call `left::operator--`, just say so: `void operator--() override { left::operator--(); }` Now the caller could write `c.operator--()`

Comment: I actually want to have the choice.

Comment: Well, you do. You can call `c.left::oeprator--()` or `c.rigth::operator--()`. I'm not sure I quite grasp the nature of the difficulty.

Comment: I am guessing this is not how it is usually done. Just that.

Comment: That whole weird tower of base classes is not how it's usually done. It's not at all clear what purpose all those classes are supposed to serve; or for that matter, what "it" is that you want done.

Comment: It could be IPrintable and many more in Common and then IComparable for Uni (Unique). Inter could be Object. Left could be IComparableBySize and right IComparableByDistance.

Comment: So, if you don't mention `IComparableBySize` in the call, how do you expect that call to know that you want comparison by size and not by distance?

Comment: Perhaps by changing some state? But then it is never done through inheritance, it's what decorators are for